# Can I just tabify begnning of lines in emacs

Tags: emacs

I like format all my code using tab instead of space, but I just want to convert spaces to tabs at the beginning of each lines.

Can tabify just convert space to tabs at the beging of lines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for `tabify` mentions a suitable value for operating on line-leading whitespace only. I used it to write this function which I find handy, but you could just set it in your init file and forego a separate function:

```
(defun tabify-leading (start end)
  "Call `tabify' with `tabify-regexp' set so that only leading
spaces are treated."
  (interactive "r")
  (setq tabify-regexp-old tabify-regexp)
  (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (setq tabify-regexp "^\t* [ \t]+")
        (tabify start end))
    (setq tabify-regexp tabify-regexp-old)))
```

Comment: Is there an `untabify` version? Modifying `tabify-regexp` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SmartTabs](http://www.emacswiki.org/SmartTabs)

It'll add onto several modes (for several languages) and make it so code indentation are tabs only, while ensuring the display of code is correct regardless of the viewer's tab width.

Excerpt:

> 1. Tabs are only used at the beginning of lines. Everything else, like ASCII art and tables, should be formatted with spaces.
> 2. Tabs are only used for expressing the indentation level. One tab per “block” – any remaining whitespace is spaces only.

Together with this, you can "tabify" existing code using the `tabify` command.

Comment: I know SmartTabs, it's good for a new file. but if i have a file that indent with spaces, and i want to change that spaces to tabs, if i use tabify in emacs, it also tabify all the spaces in the file

Comment: While `smart-tabs` is useful for managing tabs and spaces automatically, it doesn't actually do anything to the `tabify` command itself. So, `tabify` will still convert _all_ spaces to tabs (except for where that will change the display of the text) even with `smart-tabs` on.